# SQL Server: find out if user was enabled in specific periods of time

Tags: sql, sql-server, termination

I have two tables:

1. User Changes Records from the system
2. Termination dates of users from HR department (manually created list)

Changes of Users locked/unlocked status
Audit Period: 01.01.2018-31.12.2018

System Data:

```
SystemUsername;StatusChangeDate;Status;IssueFlag;Comment
user1;01.02.2018;Locked;false;
user1;04.02.2018;Unlocked;true;User was unlocked after he left the company.
user1;06.02.2018;Locked;true;User was unlocked after he left the company.
user1;01.07.2018;Unlocked;false;
user2;01.03.2018;Locked;false;
user2;01.06.2018;Unlocked;false;
user2;01.09.2018;Locked;true;User was terminated one month too late.
```

Client HR Department Data:

```
ClientGivenUsername;ClientGivenTerminationDate;ClientGivenReentryDate;ClientGivenSecondTeminationDate;
user1;01.02.2018;01.07.2018;n/a;
user2;01.03.2018;01.06.2018;01.08.2018;
```

In the above tables we have three lines that need to be flaged as an issue, beacause the user was unlocked during the time he was not working for the company according to the list from the HR department.

Can you please help me to set the IssueFlag to "true" on users that were unlocked in the period they were not employed by the company?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: the result of the query makes it hard for us to understand the model. For the data shown here, is it possible to see the two tables separated?

Comment: Can you provide us an example where the IssueFlag would be set to true? Is the Date column the date of the status change?

Comment: I'm sorry if I coused some confusion, since I'm strugeling myself it's hard to explain it but I've made a better data example with the information you requested, please see above.